# Can a Random String Generator create duplicate values, if so how to stop it?

Tags: before-trigger, duplicate-value, findduplicates

I want to know whether this code can create multiple instances of the same random number by any chance? Can i make this specific field to not have same values within salesforce it self?

```
trigger token on Certification__c (before insert) {

    for( Certification__c c: Trigger.new ) {
        final String chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
        String guid = '';
        while (guid.length() < 8) {
            Integer idx = Math.mod(Math.abs(Crypto.getRandomInteger()), chars.length());
            guid += chars.substring(idx, idx+1);
        }
        c.Name = guid; 
    }    
}
```

@@@EDIT - So i thought of adding a couple of code lines, which will check the token field c.Name whether if it has this random string value, and if it does generate new random string, if it doesn't set that string. Is this better?

Comment: You can use System.now().getTime() which will return numbers which you can add at the end of chars string. That's how you will end up a different number every time.

Comment: I want the string to be no more than 6-8 digits.

Comment: check my @@@EDIT

Comment: If you use 36 characters to choose from and you generate a random string of 8 characters long you will have 36 ^ 8 (2821109907456) different values, each occurring with the same probability. You can determine yourself if you like those odds or not. To improve the odds you can increase the number of characters to choose from (ie; make your string case sensitive and add 26 lower case letters) or increase the lenght of the string.

Comment: adding a couple of code lines, which will check the token field c.Name whether if it has this random string value, and if it does generate new random string, if it doesn't set that string. Is this better?

Comment: You can add System.now().getTime() in  final String chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a small chance of duplicates but the odds may be so low that you don't care.

You can define an [AutoNumber Custom Field](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_field_types.htm&type=5) and include that in your logic, but you will have to change your trigger to "after insert" to get the generated value and so will need to perform an update yourself.

Just saw Naval's comment and that is a better approach: the timestamp will only be the same for 1 second so combining that with the random number generation lowers the odds of a duplicate way further.

Comment: Hi, there should be no duplication what so ever, Is there a way to have an array or 
a database where i can add all the generated values and check it before when i create a new one. Is it efficient?

Comment: What do you mean it lowers the odds way further when i add the datetime, can it still create a duplicate by some miracle? and how to simplify that value to a max 8digit string

Comment: please check my @@@EDIT

Comment: @NivethKumar Your @@@EDIT approach sounds like a good one; just make sure you do a single query for all the names.